# Foreach Loop Not Display All Entries

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, foreach, gravity-forms-plugin

I created a custom function on my WordPress site that has a Gravity Form (GF) form on the site where people can pledge to create groups.  There are 7 fields on the form (Form ID #1):

1. Name
2. Email
3. Organization Name
4. Organization Address
5. # of Weekday Groups
6. # of Weekend Groups
7. Total # of Groups (hidden)

The script requests for the leads from GF form #1 and runs it through a **foreach** loop which keeps added the value from field 7 until there are no entries left.

However,  starting today the code is only gathering 30 entries from the form when there are currently 60. Please help.

```
function test_gf(){
 $pledges = RGFormsModel::get_leads('1');   // Form_id
    $group_count = 0;   // resets group_count
    $entries = 0;
        foreach ($pledges as $pledge) {
            $group_count += $pledge[7]; // Adds each value from Field #7 (Total)
            $entries++; // Checking the number of entries processed
        }

    // HTML Output
    echo '<h1>New Groups Pledged: '. $group_count . '</h1>' ;
    echo '<h2># of Entries Processed: '.$entries.'</h2>';
}
```

Comment: Look at `get_leads()` definition: may be there's some kind of default value of number of leads returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly: `$page_size=30`, override this default value with bigger number:

```
get_leads(1,0,'DESC','',0,500000)
```

Comment: So, I modified the code to be
`$pledges = RGFormsModel::get_leads('1', $page_size=100000);`

It is display a much more accurate number, but it is still not the complete list and the entries total still outputs 30. 

So, I updated the forms_model.php codes to be 5000000, which seems to have worked.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I have same version of the plugin, that's why I said to check function definition:

`get_leads($form_id, $sort_field_number=0, $sort_direction='DESC', $search='', $offset=0, $page_size=30`

it means that you should pass 5000000 in the place of $page_size parameter - in my case, the call will look like:

    get_leads(1,0,'DESC','',0,500000)

modifying plugin source code is not good because of auto-update feature.

Comment: I might try that. I hate modifying the core plugin files if possible. I will have to pass all of the arguments in the call.

Thank you.

Comment: I just updated the code to be 
`$pledges = RGFormsModel::get_leads(1,0,'DESC','',0,500000); // Form_id defined by shortcode variable
 $group_count = 0; // resets group_count
 $entries = 0;
  foreach ($pledges as $pledge) {
   $group_count += $pledge[7]; // Adds each value from Field #6 (Total)
   $entries++;
  }`

And it works perfectly especially since the documentation for GF is very limited.